# Получение значение ссылки при клике на неё

Tags: ajax

Вытаскиваю из базы (сайт на joomla) в ссылки заголовки последних 10 новостей. Для ссылок прописываю класc, например, title. Нужно сделать, чтобы при клике на ссылку без перезагрузки подгружалась полная новость соответствующего заголовка. Как это реализовать на ajax в асинхронном режиме?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема? Передаете в обработчик через ajax, скажем, id статьи, получаете вытянутую из БД статью и помещаете в нужный блок. Статей, по этому поводу, в инете больше, чем парнухи. ))

Comment: [Смотрим тут](http://bit.ly/QgeKr5)

Comment: Как мне при клике на одну из ссылок получить значение её параметра id?

    <a id="1" class="title">Ссылка 1</a>
    <a id="2" class="title">Ссылка 2</a>
    <a id="3" class="title">Ссылка 3</a>
    <a id="4" class="title">Ссылка 4</a>

Comment: Я сюда за помощью обратился, а не за тем, чтобы меня отправляли искать эту информацию в интернете.

Answer (score 3):

Мде... Помощь и "сделайте за меня" - вещи разные. Ладно, дело ваше.

> как мне при клике на одну из ссылок получить значение её параметра id?

[Смотрим пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/5pTVp/1/)

**JS**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('title'), i = elem.length;
    while(i--){
        elem[i].onclick = function(i){
            return function(){
                alert(this.id)
            };
        }(i);
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="10" class="title">Статья про Ajax</a><br />
<a id="30" class="title">Статья про JavaScript</a><br />
<a id="100500" class="title">Статья про еще что-то</a>
```

Только вместо alert() передаем параметр в функцию, которая отправляет ajax-запрос. Дальше, смотрите [пример в статье](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro)

Answer (score 1):

При помощи jQuery:

```
<a href="/article/1" class="title">Статья про Ajax</a>
<a href="/article/2" class="title">Статья про JavaScript</a>
<a href="/article/3" class="title">Статья про еще что-то</a>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.title').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).prop('href'),
            data: {},
            success: $('div.content').html,
            onerror: $('div.content').html
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Для получения атрибута id тега с классом title, используй конструкцию:

```
<a href="" id="1">Link</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.title').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).prop('id'),
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ну а вообще стоит сказать что реализовывать ajax на голом js не стоит пытаться. В инете есть куча библиотек. Учись и используй.